# I'm trying to pull data from database into selectboxes

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to pull data from database into selectboxes, but when the data is pulled it goes into one 'td' and not into separate td's. I'm trying to achieve result as shown below

[image]

---

but I keep getting this result

[image]

---

here is my code

---

```
<?php
$data_array = array();
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `firefightersonscene` 
                        JOIN `firefighterinfo` ON `firefightersonscene`.`FireFighterInfo_fighterID` = `firefighterinfo`.`fighterID` 
                        JOIN `stationlocation` ON `firefighterinfo`.`StationLocation_locationID`=`stationlocation`.`locationID` 
                        WHERE `IncidenceOfFire_incidentID`='$getIncID' ORDER BY `firstName`");

if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0)
{    
    while($rows2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2))
    {
        $data_array[] = $rows2;
    }   
}
?>
<form action="core_viewfireoccurrence.php?incidentID=<?php echo $rows->incidentID; ?>" method="post" class="view_occurrence_form">
<table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="count">1</td>
                    <td>
                            <?php 
                            foreach($data_array as $rows2):
                            $fighterID = $rows2->FireFighterInfo_fighterID; 
                            $results = mysql_query("SELECT `fighterID`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`, `stationlocation`.`exactlocation` 
                                                    FROM `firefighterinfo` 
                                                    JOIN `stationlocation` ON `firefighterinfo`.`StationLocation_locationID`=`stationlocation`.`locationID` ORDER BY `firstName`");               
                            echo '<select name="fireman[]" required><option value=""></option>';
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
                            {
                                if($row['fighterID'] == $fighterID)
                                    echo '<option selected>'. $row['firstName']." ".$row['middleName']." ".$row['lastName'].", ".$row['exactlocation'].'</option>';
                                else
                                    echo '<option>'. $row['firstName']." ".$row['middleName']." ".$row['lastName'].", ".$row['exactlocation'].'</option>';

                            }// end while
                            echo '</select><br>';
                        endforeach;
                        ?> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="X" class="removeVar"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="addVar" value="Add Item"/>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table>
</form>
```

---

JS CODE

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on('click', '.removeVar', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $('.count').each(function(i){
      $(this).text(i + 1);
    });
});

//add a new node
$('#addVar').on('click', function(){
    var varCount = $('#myTable tr').length - 1;
    $node = ['<tr>',
    '<td class="count">'+varCount+'</td>',
    '<td><select name="fireman[]" class="ctlGroup" required>',
      '<option value=""></option>',
      '<?php require("php/fireman_list.php"); ?>',
    '</select></td>',
    '<td><input type="button" value="X" class="removeVar"/>',
    '</td></tr>'].join('\n');
    $('#myTable > tbody:last').append($node);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Include your <td> into your for loop

Comment: uh, why are you embedding PHP code inside your JS? You realize that Javascript executes on the client, while PHP executes on the server? Your JS code will be hardcoded to the output of the php code at the time the page is loaded, and then never changed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your whole table row in the loop. You will also need to add a variable to count the row number for you.

```
<?php 
$row =1;
foreach($data_array as $rows2):
?>
<tr>
    <td class="count"><?php echo $row; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php    
             $fighterID = $rows2->FireFighterInfo_fighterID; 
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT `fighterID`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`, `stationlocation`.`exactlocation` 
                                    FROM `firefighterinfo` 
                                    JOIN `stationlocation` ON `firefighterinfo`.`StationLocation_locationID`=`stationlocation`.`locationID` ORDER BY `firstName`");               
            echo '<select name="fireman[]" required><option value=""></option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
            {
                if($row['fighterID'] == $fighterID)
                    echo '<option selected>'. $row['firstName']." ".$row['middleName']." ".$row['lastName'].", ".$row['exactlocation'].'</option>';
                else
                    echo '<option>'. $row['firstName']." ".$row['middleName']." ".$row['lastName'].", ".$row['exactlocation'].'</option>';

            }// end while
            echo '</select><br>';

        ?> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="X" class="removeVar"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    $row++;
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: It is somewhat working. I'm getting '1' two times and the first row doesn't have a select box, and then when the add item button is pressed, the numbering jumps to number 5. What do you suggest I should do?